# Gradle changes loading failed

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I've created a Kotlin project which uses a Gradle build system. Here's my problem:
[image]

When I click "reload gradle project" - nothing changes, I still get this mistake (project failed at...).
How can I solve this problem?
P.S: More detailed description of my problem:
When I click "reload gradle project" - it starts realoading like this:
[image]
But then it goes back to what is on the first picture (project failed at...).

Comment: Click on the failure to see the actual stack trace.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Please provide somewhere the idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file after this happens. As a possible solution, it could help to change the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**.